# Voted down question can't recover

Tags: discussion, downvotes, asking-questions, question-quality

Question: [Why are extension methods used extensively in LINQ, despite the framework's guidelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24211135/436028)

When originally asking this question I mis-quoted the source and it was down voted accordingly, however in my opinion the premise of the question still stood.

Regardless I have now resolved the mis-quote and voted to re-open.  The question still stands in a 'down-trodden' state therefore I'm asking for advice:

- Is the question still unsuitable for stackoverflow?
- Perhaps it's just not getting the 'views' it needs?

Any direction / advice regarding where I went wrong here is much appreciated.

Comment: Asking on Meta will be a kick in the shorts one way or the other. As for me, it seems like a valid question now. I've cast an upvote and a re-open vote. (And even with the misquotation, I would object to the closure.)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm more interested in how to avoid what happened in the future, regardless of what happens to this question (I was of mind to delete it but that wouldn't be fair on the excellent answers).

Comment: No, don't delete it. And you can't really avoid downvotes. But you will attract them in spades if the question has a fundamental flaw, like misquoting the documentation. You already know that, though, so there's little point in me beating a dead horse. Having fixed it now, you might flag it and ask a moderator to delete the obsolete comments.

Comment: The quote may have been updated but the question still seems to rely on a faulty premise.

Comment: @OGHaza - Not sure I agree, I read avoiding incrementing version number as avoiding modifying your code (they are mutually inclusive after all)